# Is the Xbox 360 controller compatible with RT games under Windows 8?

Tags: controllers, windows-rt

I don't have an Xbox however i am planning to buy a *Microsoft Xbox 360 Controller* for Windows 8 PC.

As of now (and as per my RnD), current Xbox 360 controller is compatible with Surface RT and most of the games on it.

Does the same holds true for RT games we download from Windows 8.1 store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, the Controller will work with Windows RT-Games, because Windows will recognize the Pad, no matter if it's Windows 7, 8, 8.1 or RT. Even Windows Phone works. Have a look at 
[this Youtube-Video covering Windows RT (Surface) + XBox 360 Controller](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAeRADR8Vqc). This channel has some other RT-Videos too (i.e. USB-Tests and more). I may be wrong, but I think you can even navigate through the tiles on Windows 8/8.1 with the Gamepad.

Keep in mind that the games need to support a gamepad.

Comment: What about games Xbox one games/its ports coming to Windows 8 Store. Will they support XBOX 360 controller. I dont want to buy a xbox 360 controller only to have it not supported just because of new xbox one :)

Comment: I doubt anyone can answer that until the new xbox is released. I don't own any xbox and use the gamepad for windows games ;)